# How to access each element of Date in Pig Latin?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Query:

```
records = LOAD 'input' using PigStorage(' ') as (id:int, name:chararray, desination:chararray, date:chararray, salary: long);
```

Sample input:

```
    (10102,neha,developer,14/02/13,32000)

    (10103,deva,admin,02/02/14,40000)

    (10102,neha,developer,01/01/14,45000)

    (10245,sasi,developer,01/01/14,20000)

    (10109,surya,manager,01/02/2014,56000)

    (10102,neha,developer,01/02/2014,45000)

    (10245,sasi,developer,02/01/2014,25000)
```

I want to filter the above data based on year of the date(not entire date).

Comment: can u paste your sample output which you want?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you.

```
records = LOAD '/home/abhijit/Downloads/movies.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, desination:chararray, date:chararray, salary:int);

todate_data = foreach records generate id,name,destination,date, salary,ToDate(date,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') as (date_time:DateTime );

todate_data = foreach records generate name,desination,ToDate(date,'dd/MM/yyyy') as (date_time:DateTime );

getyear_data = foreach todate_data generate name,desination,GetYear(date_time);

groupByYear = group getyear_data by $3;
```

The final output will be :

```
(2013,{(neha,developer,2013)})
(2014,{(deva,admin,2014),(neha,developer,2014),(sasi,developer,2014),(surya,manager,2014),(neha,developer,2014),(sasi,developer,2014)})
```

Comment: Thank you Abhijit. I appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: @Dhiraj accept the answer if it solved your problem so other can know that this is right answer. If not solved your problem but help you then you can vote-up.